# Angular using npm local libraries leads to DI error : ERROR Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context

Tags: angular

[solved] See my comment to get answer

[original title]
Angular libraries that expose a Service requiring Environment : ERROR Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context

[original post]
I have a problem building a simple library (angular 17.3) that contain a DummyService (for this issue, it's simpler to use a DummyService) that use environment file.

I started a project with angular cli `ng new dummy-library --no-create-application` and i also added a demo project to use the library `cd dummy-library && ng generate project demo`.

Then i first build an InjectionToken to be able to expose the environment file as a service :

```
export const ENVIRONMENT_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<Environment>('Environment');
```

Then i reuse this in my service like this :

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DummyService {
  private environment: Environment = inject(ENVIRONMENT_TOKEN);

  log() {
    console.log(this.environment);
  }
}
```

Both are added in the public-api.ts that export all required files to expose them :

```
export * from './lib/environment.token';
export * from './lib/dummy.service';
```

I can build the library with a command like this `ng build --project=dummy-library`

Now i can use the library from the demo app really easily and it works well. I just have to provide the service in the component like this :

```
import { DummyService, ENVIRONMENT_TOKEN } from 'dummy-library'; // it import from dist folder created during ng build process

providers: [
    DummyService,
    {
      provide: ENVIRONMENT_TOKEN,
      useValue: environment
    }
  ],
```

And inject the serice to the appComponent :

```
DummyService = inject(DummyService);
```

Perfect !
But, if i want to use the library in another project using npm, then i have an injection problem.

Fist i create my new application `ng new anotherApplication`;

Then i add the library `cd another-application && npm install ../dummy-library/dist/dummy-library/` and i create the environment `ng generate environment`

Then i provide the service in the AppComponent like i did previously and i inject the DummyService in the AppComponent.
I serve the app `ng serve`. The app is built and served, but in the browser, i have an error in the console :

```
main.ts:5 ERROR Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:1093:15)
    at ɵɵinject (core.mjs:1106:42)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.DummyService_Factory [as factory] (dummy.service.ts:7:26)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:5984:44)
    at searchTokensOnInjector (core.mjs:5911:16)
    at lookupTokenUsingNodeInjector (core.mjs:5860:34)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:5772:23)
    at ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:10548:19)
    at ɵɵinject (core.mjs:1106:42)
    at inject (core.mjs:1192:12)
```

If i inject the environment in the Appcomponent, i can debug and see that it works. But i cannot inject the DummyService that rely on the InjectionToken.

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: In fact the problem is not related to the library or the project. It is related to the fact that when doing npm install from local project, it will create a symlink from your node_modules to the local library. But it seems that Angular ng serve command doesn't work finely with this. If you do `npm install PATH_TO_LOCAL_LIBRARY_DIST --install-links` then it will works as expected.